# Redmine/Rails - Undefined method while sending POST data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post, redmine

Redmine allows the user to add files to a document manually, my goal is to create a method that does that automatically.

I've added a file manually while sniffing with Wireshark to get the POST requests that I want to recreate in my method to help me a little bit (I can't post some screenshots (if needed), my reputation is too low).

Redmine official website offers informations to how attach files here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Attaching-files

So after hours browsing the Web and particulary StackOverflow and [here](https://coderwall.com/p/c-mu-a), I finally wrote a method:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("/uploads.js")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'})
request.body = File.new("/home/testFile.txt", 'rb')
@response = http.request(request)
```

As explained on the Redmine website I specified the content-type in the header and I added the file in the body request.

Now I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1404:in `addr_port'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1339:in `begin_transport'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1315:in `transport_request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
plugins/redmine_reddrop/app/controllers/projectusers_controller.rb:360:in `addFile'
```

EDIT:

I updated my uri with an absolute URL like this:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://<server_IP_address>:3000/uploads.js")
```

And now I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `bytesize' for #<File:/home/testFile.txt>):
```

Do you see any error in my method or do you have any idea where does this error come from?

Note: I'm using rails 3.2.16 and Ruby 1.9.3-p392

Comment: Your URI is just a filename. When creating the `Net::HTTP` object, you are calling its port. This might be nil, so the HTTP class _clould_ be unable to build the request properly when the supplied port is nil.

Comment: Please print `uri.host` and `uri.port` before assigning `http` and post their content if those are not `nil`.

Comment: Both are `nil`. Should I defined these variables by myself so ? I assume the port is 80 and the host would be redmine.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot use a relative URI so your line

```
uri = URI.parse('/uploads.js')
```

cannot be correctly processed.
Try using the absolute URL ! And it will probably work.

I believe that instead of

```
request.body = File.new(...)
```

You should use

```
request.body = File.read(...)
```

Comment: I updated my uri like this: `uri = URI.parse("http://<server_IP_address>:3000/uploads.js")` because I'm working on a distant server where I've installed Redmine and I'm now getting another error:`(undefined method `bytesize' for #<File:/home/testFile.txt>`. Another problem is if someone install my plugin on his Redmine platform the code must be modified that's why I put a relative address.

Comment: You can also find the current url in another way I guess. If you are in a controller, you can for instance use `request.original_url`
And I updated my answer

Comment: Ok I didn't know that, thanks. I'll update my post with the new informations and with the new error message.

Comment: Are you sure there is a file at `/home/testFile.txt`? This error message looks like it would not be there.

Comment: Yes I am, I've just checked

Comment: Finally I solved the problem, thanks to you, that gave me hints to continue. The request doesn't work tough, I face another problem (CSRF Token stuff) but I'm gonna do a new post for that. Thanks alot.